# Laravel 5.6 -> POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/posts 500 (Internal Server Error)

Tags: laravel-5, http-status-code-500

*When I Am trying to access API and add the protected $appends = ['avatar'] it gives me the error while in case I remove the $appends the error go.*

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;


class User extends Authenticatable
{
use Notifiable;

/**
 * The attributes that are mass assignable.
 *
 * @var array
 */
 protected $fillable = [
    'username', 'email', 'password',
 ];

 protected $appends = ['avatar'];

 /**
 * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
 *
 * @var array
 */
 protected $hidden = [
    'password', 'remember_token',
 ];

 public function posts()
 { 
   return $this->hasMany(Post::class);
 }

 public function getAvatar(){
   return 'https://gravatar.com/avatar/'.md5($this->email).'/?d=mm&s=45';
 }

 public function getAvatarAtribute(){
   return $this->getAvatar();
   }
 }
```

When I go to the network trace I see this tip  -> message: "Method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::getAvatarAttribute does not exist."

Answer (score 1):

Just checked your code you have to declare as

```
 public function getAvatarAttribute(){
   return $this->getAvatar();
   }
```

Attribute instead of atribute